# C++ code for branch and price

Tags: column-generation, c++, branch-and-price

I looking to learn to use bpcolumn generation techniques in c++.

Does any body know of GitHub repository or any other site where I can find some code And learn about it...
The application can be anything like a vrp....

Answer (score 4):

Out of the multiple options, the open-source option is Coin-OR's BCP (Branch-Cut-Price) [[github](https://github.com/coin-or/Bcp)]. SCIP also offers branch-and-price via its GCG    (generic branch-cut-and-price) solver [[link](https://gcg.or.rwth-aachen.de/)].

Comment: as the public GCG documentation is miserable, I can give you access to what we internally use in preparation for an improved website...

Comment: Yes...sir...please that would be really helpful....can you share some links...

Comment: There is also [Coin-OR's DIP](https://github.com/coin-or/Dip)